# android wont refresh customlistview from outside adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I'm using [this horizontal list view](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView) but it wont refresh the view when i call notify notifyDataSetChanged()
Mainactivity class

```
   oncreate{
    products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    listView = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, products);
    listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, products));
```

...

```
private void loadProduct(Intent data) {

    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    Product p  = (Product)extras.getParcelable(PASSED_PRODUCT);

    //tried using imageAdapter.add(p) aswell but doesnt work either
   products.add(p);
   imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

..

ImageAdapter class

```
            public void add(Product p) {
    products.add(p);
            // notify the list that the underlying model has changed
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void remove(int position) {

    products.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

if i have a buttonlistener to remove items inside the imageadapter class which removes items off the list fine and refreshes properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, results);
listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, results));
```

You're creating two different `ImageAdapter`s.  Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `imageAdapter` does not affect the other `ImageAdapter`.

I think you meant to do this:

```
imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, results);
listView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```